# I need to import a database using the system php function

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have a script that exports database using the system function.

```
$command = "c:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump --opt -uuser -ppassword-  --databases movies --result-file=export.php";
system($command);
```

I need to know the equivalent to import a database.

I am using xampp and windows 8

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. However, in order to execute a command you need to use `shell_exec(command)` in PHP. If you need the script to export the records let me know. I will post it

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this, with a mysqli object

```
$sql = file_get_contents('location/of/import.sql');
if($conn->multi_query($sql)){
    while($conn->more_results() and $conn->next_result()){
        ;
    }
};
```

Comment: The only issue I may run into with this is if the file is too large and I have a memory issue because I have to store the entire file in a varible

Comment: It's not ideal, but you can temporarily up the PHP memory limit for a script. I do this for what I consider to be "one off" pages (like you're import script, or a complex report generator) http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-memory-limit-ini_set